# How to identify the last completed dag among all the running dag instances in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

It is a scheduled-based DAG. The airflow created 4 instances of dag, and I want to identify the last completed dag instance ie. `d-instance-2`. which is completed at the end of all dag-instance.

is there any way in airflow to identify the last completed dag among all the running dag instances?

| dag-instance | dag - run order | dag-completion order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d-instance - 1 | run - 1 | complete - 1 - first (need to identify) |
| d-instance - 2 | run - 2 | complete - 4 - last (need to identify) |
| d-instance - 3 | run - 3 | complete - 2 |
| d-instance - 4 | run - 4 | complete - 3 |

```
dag_args = {
"depends_on_past": False,
"start_date": datetime(2017, 1, 1),
"end_date": datetime(2020, 12, 31)}


dag = DAG("Multiple_dag_instance will trigger",
      description='dag_description',
      default_args=dag_args,
      schedule_interval="@yearly")

chain(
  task_1,
  task_2,
  identify_the_final_dag_completion_task)
```

Here, `start_date: datetime(2017, 1, 1)` and  `end_date: datetime(2020, 12, 31)` create 4 yearly dag instance of year 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit about the context and use of the DAG? Why you need to identify the last running instance? Why you want to chain the `task_2` with the `identify_the_final_dag_completion_task`? What type of operators are those?

Comment: This information can be accessed via a SQL query in the UI. Would it be enough to answer your need ?

Comment: @bruno-uy, want to trigger notification task after the end of all the dags instances are successfully completed. It is based on `PythonOperator`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python code to query the Dag Runs corresponding to the DAG id and filter by execution start date, then sort the dags by end date and pick those you want.

You could try something similar to the following:

```py
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from datetime import datetime

# Your execution date here. Maybe ds injected with Jinja templates.
exec_date = datetime.strptime('2021-05-19', '%Y-%m-%d')

dag_ids = ['dag_id_1', 'dag_id_2']

runs = DagRun.find(dag_ids, execution_start_date=exec_date)
runs.sort(key=lambda x: x.end_date)
```

I tested this on a python shell on a host running airflow 2.1.0 and worked. I believe it should work the same for you from within an operator's execute.

Comment: It gives us all running dags information, the requirement is to identify the dag's all instances were successfully completed, and then I have a 
trigger/callback the notification task within chain.

Comment: @eigenharsha That's weird. It should show you all DagRuns, running or not. You should even be able to filter by its state - running, success, etc. [API Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.find). Are you using the right `execution_start_date`?

Comment: @eigenharsha also: how do you wait for the DAGs? are these subdags or you literally trigger a new dag? I take the last task should somehow wait for all dags to be finished and then query them, otherwise they'll for sure be running if you launch and continue.